Implement Map using composite unordered keys
In javascript a Map allows uniquely retrieving a "value" based on a single associated "key" - like so:
let m = new Map();
m.set('a', 'my value');

let v = m.get('a'); // v === 'my value'

How can we implement a data structure which uses multiple unordered keys to retrieve an associated value? In such a case the "key" value would always be an array. Let's call this a "CompoundMap". Let's allow a CompoundMap to be instantiated with a "width" value, giving a fixed-size for its compound keys. Like Map, the values used in CompoundMap keys should be able to be anything (e.g. String, Number, Object, Regex, ClientRequest... whatever) E.g.:
let cm = new CompoundMap({ width: 2 });
cm.set([ 'a', 1 ], 'my value');

let v1 = cm.get([ 'a', 1 ]); // v1 === 'my value'
let v2 = cm.get([ 1, 'a' ]); // v2 === 'my value'
let v3 = cm.get([ 'a', 2 ]); // v3 === undefined
let v4 = cm.get([ 'b', 1 ]); // v4 === undefined
let v5 = cm.get([ 2, 'a' ]); // v5 === undefined
let v6 = cm.get([ 1, 'b' ]); // v6 === undefined

One way I can think of is to use a nested trees of Maps:


class CompoundMap {
  
  constructor({ width, entries }) {
    
    if (!width && entries) width = entries[0]?.[0]?.length;
    if (!width) throw Error('Must provide "width"');
    
    Object.assign(this, { width, tree: new Map() });
    
    for (let [ cmpKey, val ] of entries ?? []) this.set(cmpKey, val);
    
  }
  
  * treeSearch(tree, cmpKey) {
    
    if (cmpKey.length === 0) throw Error('Compound key should have at least one item');
    
    // A `cmpKey` with length 1 is our "base case"; return the "tree" we reached, and the final key
    if (cmpKey.length === 1) return yield { tree, finalKey: cmpKey[0] };
    
    for (let [ n, key ] of cmpKey.entries()) {
      
      let subtree = tree.get(key);
      
      // If no `subtree`, `key` doesn't apply at this current depth
      if (!subtree) continue;
      
      // We found a `subtree` - we still need to process the remaining key, which is `cmpKey` with `key` removed
      let cmpKeyMinusKey = (() => {
        let copy = [ ...cmpKey ];
        copy.splice(n, 1); // `n` is the index of `key` in `copy`
        return copy;
      })();
      
      // Now recursively search for the rest of the key! Note `yield*` helps us implement backtracking - a
      // search down some specific chain of subtrees may not succeed, but the overall search could still
      // succeed when another chain of subtrees is able to fully consume the `cmpKey`
      // (This is also why the runtime for this approach will be horrible...)
      yield* this.treeSearch(subtree, cmpKeyMinusKey);
      
    }
    
  }
  
  set(cmpKey, val) {
    
    if (cmpKey.length !== this.width) throw Error(`Compound key must have exactly ${this.width} item(s)`);
    
    let preexisting = this.treeSearch(this.tree, cmpKey).next().value;
    
    if (preexisting) {
      
      // Overwrite existing item
      // `this.treeSearch` yields `{ tree, finalKey }`, so overwriting is very simple
      let { tree, finalKey } = preexisting;
      tree.set(finalKey, val);
      
    } else {
      
      // Write new item
      let tree = this.tree;
      for (let k of cmpKey.slice(0, -1)) {
        if (!tree.has(k)) tree.set(k, new Map());
        tree = tree.get(k);
      }
      
      tree.set(cmpKey.at(-1), val);
      
    }
    
    return this;
    
  }
  
  get(cmpKey) {
    
    if (cmpKey.length !== this.width) throw Error(`Compound key must have exactly ${this.width} item(s)`);
    
    let preexisting = this.treeSearch(this.tree, cmpKey).next().value;
    if (!preexisting) return undefined;
    
    let { tree, finalKey } = preexisting;
    return tree.get(finalKey);
    
  }
  
}

let obj1 = { desc: 'obj' };
let obj2 = { desc: 'obj' };
let tests = [
  
  {
    entries: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 1 ], val: 'my value' },
    ],
    lookups: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 1 ], expected: 'my value' },
      { cmpKey: [ 1, 'a' ], expected: 'my value' },
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 2 ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 'b', 1 ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 2, 'a' ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 1, 'b' ], expected: undefined }
    ]
  },

  {
    entries: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], val: obj1 },
      { cmpKey: [ 'c', 'd', 'e' ], val: obj2 }
    ],
    lookups: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 'd', 'e' ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 'c', 'b', 'a' ], expected: obj1 },
      { cmpKey: [ 'd', 'e', 'c' ], expected: obj2 }
    ]
  }
  
];

for (let { entries, lookups } of tests) {
  
  let cm = new CompoundMap({ entries: entries.map(({ cmpKey, val }) => [ cmpKey, val ]) });
  
  for (let { cmpKey, expected } of lookups) {
    
    let received = cm.get(cmpKey);
    
    if (received !== expected) {
      console.log(`Test Failed! Expected [ ${cmpKey.join(', ')} ] -> ${JSON.stringify(expected)} ... BUT GOT ${JSON.stringify(received)}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Test Passed! [ ${cmpKey.join(', ')} ] -> ${JSON.stringify(expected)}`);
    }
    
  }
  
}



If you follow the above logic, however, you will see that the runtime is horrible - I think it's at least exponential (O(2^n)). Can a CompoundMap be implemented more efficiently?
If we could somehow map arbitrary values to BigInts, through a function like getUniqueIntFor, we could map compound keys to single unique Strings:
let compoundKey = [ 1, 2, 'j', /my regex/u, { arr: [] }, new HttpServer() ];
let uniqueString = compoundKey
  .map(anyValue => getUniqueIntFor(anyValue).toString(36))
  .sort()
  .join('.');

Given this ability, it's arbitrary to implement CompoundMap. But how to implement getUniqueIntFor?
Is this idea worthwhile?
Otherwise, how can I implement CompoundMap more efficiently?

You're looking for a hash function for arbitrary types. You could either implement your own function or use a library, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash

you can sort the keys, check my answer

@jabaa not quite as simple as hashing arbitrary values because hash({}) === hash({}), but {} !== {}.

You want a unique number for every possible value? I think, that's impossible.

@jabaa If there was a js function to get memory address it would potentially be trivial! (Basically what * does in C). I'm lately thinking there's a possibility to use a WeakMap and reference counting to associate every new value with a generated unique value (basically an incrementing counter).

It wouldn't work with memory addresses. That's the reason why {} == {}. You want to use a literal to access an entry, but the second literal has a different memory address than the first literal. You want two literals to have the same hash (otherwise cm.get([ 'a', 1 ]) would always return undefined) and each value to have a unique hash. That's impossible. You want cm.set([ 'a', 1 ], 'my value'); cm.get([ 'a', 1 ]); to return 'my value', but [ 'a', 1 ] !== [ 'a', 1 ]. You need a bijective mapping between all possible JavaScript values and natural numbers.

Reference counting won't work, too. In cm.set([ 'a', 1 ], 'my value'); cm.get([ 'a', 1 ]);, the first array would have id 1 and the second id 2. You would get undefined. You need a mapping from values to numbers, but I don't think, it can return unique values. It's a hash.

@GershomMaes Is the key an array of primitives or an array of arbitrary JavaScript values including nested arrays and objects?

@jabaa the array isn't intended to be the key - the key is the unordered compound aggregate of the array values

But the array values are only primitives?

@jabaa Not just primitives, same as Map! (You can also see the tests using obj1 and obj2)

I meant the array values from the key array.

Ah sorry I got confused - but yes, I would like to support any value in the CompoundMap key array

In that case, the given answer doesn't work. It doesn't work with nested arrays.

@jabaa I'm not sure I follow you 100%, but note that let cm = new CompoundMap(); cm.set([ [ 1, 2 ] ], 'abc'); console.log(cm.get([ [ 1, 2 ] ])) should output undefined, as [ 1, 2 ] !== [ 1, 2 ].

@jabaa You'd need a reference to the exact same array; e.g. let cm = new CompoundMap(); let arr = [ 1, 2 ]; cm.set([ arr ], 'abc'); arr.push(3); console.log(cm.get([ arr ])); should output 'abc'.

As a user of this library, I would expect a value-wise comparison, not a reference comparison.

@jabaa Try the following: let m = new Map(); m.set([ 1, 2 ], 'abc'); console.log(m.get([ 1, 2 ]));

I would expect let cm = new CompoundMap(); cm.set([ [ 1, 2 ] ], 'abc'); console.log(cm.get([ [ 1, 2 ] ])) to log 'abc'. Otherwise, you're library doesn't support nested arrays as keys.

You can easily sort the keys (the sorting could be optimized of course), that makes working with the tree very simple.


class CompoundMap{
  #idxs = new Map;
  #tree = new Map;
  constructor(entries){
    for(const entry of entries) this.set(entry[0], entry[1]);
  }
  get(keys){
    const sorted = this.sortKeys(keys);
    let tree = this.#tree;
    for(const key of sorted){
      tree = tree.get(key)?.tree
      if(!tree) return;
    }
    return tree.value;
  }
  sortKeys(keys){
    let idx;
    return keys.map(key => (idx = this.#idxs.get(key) ?? (this.#idxs.set(key, idx = this.#idxs.size), idx), idx)).sort((a,b) => a-b);
  }
  set(keys,val){
    const sorted = this.sortKeys(keys);
    let tree = this.#tree;
    for(const key of sorted){
      let next = tree.get(key);
      if(!next){
        next = {tree: new Map};
        tree.set(key, next);
      }
      tree = next.tree;
    }
    tree.value = val;
  }
}

let obj1 = { desc: 'obj' };
let obj2 = { desc: 'obj' };
let tests = [
  
  {
    entries: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 1 ], val: 'my value' },
    ],
    lookups: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 1 ], expected: 'my value' },
      { cmpKey: [ 1, 'a' ], expected: 'my value' },
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 2 ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 'b', 1 ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 2, 'a' ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 1, 'b' ], expected: undefined }
    ]
  },

  {
    entries: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], val: obj1 },
      { cmpKey: [ 'c', 'd', 'e' ], val: obj2 }
    ],
    lookups: [
      { cmpKey: [ 'a', 'd', 'e' ], expected: undefined },
      { cmpKey: [ 'c', 'b', 'a' ], expected: obj1 },
      { cmpKey: [ 'd', 'e', 'c' ], expected: obj2 }
    ]
  }
  
];

for (let { entries, lookups } of tests) {
  
  let cm = new CompoundMap(entries.map(({ cmpKey, val }) => [ cmpKey, val ]) );
  
  for (let { cmpKey, expected } of lookups) {

    let received = cm.get(cmpKey);
    
    if (received !== expected) {
      console.log(`Test Failed! Expected [ ${cmpKey.join(', ')} ] -> ${JSON.stringify(expected)} ... BUT GOT ${JSON.stringify(received)}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Test Passed! [ ${cmpKey.join(', ')} ] -> ${JSON.stringify(expected)}`);
    }
    
  }
  
}




Interesting... but it looks like this is essentially implementing getUniqueIntFor? I think #idxs is a memory leak... maybe if every key -> int mapping was reference-counted and removed when the key is no longer in use? Sorting the keys is a very good insight.

@GershomMaes yes, like getUniqueIntFor, you could try WeakMap to avoid memory leaks

@GershomMaes a composite string key is usually slower than a tree of maps, i'll try to benchmark later

This doesn't work with nested structures: https://jsfiddle.net/o7sk6g2j/ I'm not sure, what "the values used in CompoundMap keys should be able to be anything (e.g. String, Number, Object, Regex, ClientRequest... whatever)" means, if the keys have to primitves or complex structures.

@jabaa i believe there's was no goal to support nested arrays. otherwise just flatten the key array

I don't think that you can flatten it. I would expect [[1, 2], 3] and [1, [2, 3]] to be different keys.

@jabaa i think according to the op the keys should behave like keys for Map, nothing else

I think,  you're right. The sentence confused me.

It looks like I wasn't confused: "Ah sorry I got confused - but yes, I would like to support any value in the CompoundMap key array" is a comment under the question.

@jabaa as i understand from the OP's code, no key array flattening ‍♂️

I implemented this and pushed it to github and npm - I decided to reference-count the WeakMap entries; this allows entries to be removed earlier, when the user has deleted keys, but not yet dropped all references to the items in those keys.
